# How to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a feedVC which shows updates from all user. I'm retrieving data from firebase and want the height to set automatically depending on the post length.  the problem is, even after returning UITableViewAutomaticDimension from heightForRowAt, the cells don't resize automatically when the VC is first launched. if I navigate to other vc and come back to the feedVc it is working fine. Images Attached

**When VC is launched for the first time**

[image]

**After switching to another VC from tabbar and then again tapping on feed, it's giving the desired results.**

[image]

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet weak var tableviewFeed: UITableView!
    var listPost = [Posts]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listPost.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableviewFeed.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell") as! FeedCell
    cell.lblUser.sizeToFit()
    cell.lblPost.sizeToFit()
    cell.lblUser.text = listPost[indexPath.row].user
    cell.lblPost.text = listPost[indexPath.row].post
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableviewFeed.estimatedRowHeight = 100
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    FirebaseService.instance.retrievePost { (post) in
        self.listPost = post.reversed()
        self.tableviewFeed.reloadData()
    }

}
}
```

Comment: can you try updating cellForRowAt like this,
`cell.lblUser.text = listPost[indexPath.row].user
 cell.lblPost.text = listPost[indexPath.row].post
 cell.lblUser.sizeToFit()
 cell.lblPost.sizeToFit()
 return cell`

Comment: I think you need to call that `cell.lblUser.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: @kamran tried that, didn't work.

Comment: @shabirjan calling 'layoutIfNeeded()' worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
cell.lblUser.layoutIfNeeded()
```

after

```
cell.lblUser.sizeToFit()
```